# affecting an HTML page before opening it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a site for my g/f – She's writing angel messages for each day of the year, 1 message on 1 page and these (eventually 366 pages) are accessed from this one page:

http://www.helderziendelezingen.be/waarzegster-engelen-leggingen/per-datum.html

This menu page uses JS  to slide to particular months. The place I'm stuck is how could it be possible to go from a particular days message, back to the month of that message in the per-datum page (having the page slid to that month)...

for clarities sake... “Terug” means “back”, so for example to click on october 22nd message, read the message, and terug back to Octobers seeds rather than back to the per datum pages month selection calender.

My best effort so far is to put this in the a tag:

onclick="document.getElementById('waarzegstermove').style.cssText='left: -1000px;';"

-1000px would be Januarys terugs, -2000px Februarys terugs etc to have it already slid to that month, this code works when on the same page, but when its on the message page before loading up the per datum page it seems to lose this setting.

I would really appreciate help on this – to be honest I've never used cookies, I dont know what they're for, am I on the right track, is there something else involved like location: hash? or is this what cookies are for?

many thanks, Will

Comment: You don't need cookies for this. Javascript can be used to load the page contents into a box out of the view, and then scroll box into the view. And on back, scroll the box out. There should be some premade JS for this kind of navigation with AJAX, but I don't remember a specific one. So JS is your key. There are also some page transitions on IE, but it's IE specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this: create a div for the days and the message. When you click on a day, slide the days div up, effectively hiding it, while sliding the message div down. The "back" button on the message page would do the opposite. I'd guess you'd need an AJAX request to display the correct message in its div tho. An alternative would be to load all messages for a given month and also slide them horizontally. Hope it's of use t you.

Comment: Hi guys and thanks for the input - SuperDuck, yes as it turns out using premade JS was the way, the jquery coda slider function found here at ndoherty.biz is pretty neat - it scrolls with a variety of available scroll transition options (e.g. moving fast slow fast), while at the same time adding a #number reference to the URL - so basically exactly what i wanted - if anyones interested you can see it in action on the UK "sister" site here: http://www.clairvoyantangelreadings.co.uk/psychic-readings/clairvoyant-messages.html

Comment: mingos - its a great idea and naturally probably my preference, although I felt for SEO reasons creating a page for each message had added value - at one time I thought then of having a page for each message and the main page referencing these individual pages (grabbing the data from them) although I also wanted the messages to look good when opened as individuals themselves, so many thanks again for the thought provoking input. best wishes

Comment: ps obviously with reference to the above, the "seo" on that site isnt finished - still needs basic page titles etc, and if anyone else finds this page and wants to use the javascript - it helps having a blank first panel .... so to start the panels at #2, otherwise when opening the page it doesn't look great on some browsers as it loads panel #1 for an instant before opening the desired one...